# KeyboardDatePicker MaterialUI - custom mask format

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui, mask, date-formatting

When using Material UI's KeyboardDatePicker it doesn't allow users to input letters when the format is dd/MMM/yyyy (ex. 26/Apr/1983). How would I create a mask to create a custom format?

My attempt so far has been something like this:

```
<KeyboardDatePicker
    mask={[
      /\d/,
      /\d/,
      "/",
      /[a-zA-Z]/,
      /[a-zA-Z]/,
      /[a-zA-Z]/,
      "/",
      /\d/,
      /\d/
    ]}
    format="dd/MMM/yyyy"
    placeholder="DD/MMM/YYYY"
    label="Date of birth"
    openTo="year"
    views={["year", "month", "date"]}
    value={selectedDate}
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mask can accept `string` only so in your case, the regex array will not work.

There is another flag called `refuse` which can be used to refuse the pattern in the input. We can make use of it to allow alphabetic input.

Here is the codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-pickers-keyboard-birthdate-forked-hmtgv?file=/src/index.js

```js
const refusePattern = () => {
    return /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/gi; //reject the pattern which is not a-z, A-Z and 0-9
};

<KeyboardDatePicker
   ...
   refuse={refusePattern()}

/>
```